# What operator can return the median of close pixels?

Tags: image, image-processing

I have a binarized image like the folowing matrix:

```
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
```

The problem is that the image stars and end with 101, so how can i turn that into this.

```
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

I am trying to the decode the image binary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like resizing original image with scale (0.5,1) using Nearest Neighbor method.

Comment: that helped, but for example where i wanted to get a 0001011 the output was 00011011

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Matlab or any other language with similar array processing capabilities (APL, Fortran 90, Mathematica, C++ +Boost, ...) you could turn your input into your desired output  with a statement similar to this:

```
arr(:,1:2:end)
```

if your array of pixels is called `arr` of course.

This does not return the median of close pixels, but then nor does the suggested output in the question.

Comment: i'm using C# with the Emgu Cv.